# descontar items de mi stock principal cuando en el modelo Order elcampo estado obtenga un aprobado?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
se requiere que cuando el modelo Order recibe en el campo estado la palabra 'aprobado' los productos agregados en order item se resten del inventario del modelo Caracteristica

este es el modelo Caracteristica:

```
lass Caracteristica(models.Model):
opcion = models.ForeignKey(Producto, verbose_name="Opcion", related_name="opcionCaracteristica", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
codigoP = models.CharField(verbose_name="Codigo", null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
descripcion = models.CharField(verbose_name="Descripcion", max_length=100, help_text="respuesta segun pregunta anterior")
precio = models.CharField(verbose_name="Precio", max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
precioPromo = models.CharField(verbose_name="precio promo", max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)  
minimo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Pedido minimo", default=1, blank=False, null=False)  
disponibles = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Disponibles", blank=False, null=False)
UMedida = models.ForeignKey(UnidadM, verbose_name="Unidad de medida", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

el campo disponibles es el stock principal.

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name="opcionCaracteristica"
    verbose_name_plural = "opcionCaracteristicas"
    ordering = ['id']

def __str__(self):
    return self.codigoP

class Order(models.Model):
usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
estado = models.CharField(max_length=50)
precio_total = models.IntegerField()
invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=increment_invoice_number, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name="Order"
    verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
    ordering = ['-id']

def __str__(self):
    return 'Order {}'.format(self.invoice_no)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
producto = models.ForeignKey(Caracteristica, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
orden = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.id)

def get_cost(self):
    return self.price * self.cantidad
```

el model Caracteristica es la base de datos principal y que cuando se genere la compra o cuando el campo estado de Order cambie a 'aprobado' se descuente los productos de esa orden en Caracteristica.
Gracias por su colaboracion.

Comment: Quieres que cuando se cree una instancia del modelo `OrderItem` se elimine automáticamente una **instancia random** del modelo `Caracteristica`?

Comment: si señor es q no he podido dar con ese tema la verdad soy novato.

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: buena noche, ps la verdad ya habia intentado algo asi de signals pero aun asi no me funciono. probe el estilo que me colaboraste por sierto muchas gracias, pero no me funciono igual. el detalle es q aun asi necesito que cuando el model order cambie el estado a aprobado las cantidades de  productos de orderitem se descuenten de mi modelo Caracteristica.

Comment: Esto no lo aclaraste en tu pregunta y al parecer es un problema algo complejo ya que tengo ciertas dudas respecto a el. Actualiza tu pregunta con **todo el problema**, con detalles, etc, de esta manera podre entender con mayor claridad el problema y así ayudarte.

Comment: ok ya cambie de cierta manera el modo de la pregunta, de igual manera le agradezco su colaboracion.

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacerlo lo ideal es utilizar señales, específicamente la señal [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender = Order)
def delete_order_items(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Si entra al if, es que la orden ha sido aprobada
    if instance.estado == 'aprobado':
        for order_intem in instance.orderitem_set.all():
            order_intem.producto.disponibles = abs(order_intem.cantidad - order_intem.producto.disponibles)
            order_intem.producto.save()
```

De esta manera cada ves que **actualices o crees** una instancia del modelo `Order` y su campo `estado` tenga el valor de `"aprobado"` se restara el campo `disponibles`de la instancia relacionada del modelo `Caracteristica`, que se relaciona con la instancia del modelo `OrderItem`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias Julio Cesar por su ayuda pero aun no e funciona el detalle.

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: el signal no hace efecto en el stock principal

Comment: Dijiste que querías que cada ves que una instancia del modelo Order y su campo estado tenga el valor de "aprobado" se eliminara automáticamente todas las instancias relacionadas del modelo OrderItem. Quieres que se eliminen tambien las instancias del modelo Caracteristica?

Comment: si es q mi principal objetivo es Caracteristica, order y orderitem son el modelo de la orden de compra. quiero de esa orden de compra los productos agregados o comprados se descuenten de Caracteristica. como tal quiero algo parecido a esto cantidad = int(prod.disponibles) - int(instance.cantidad)

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta, ahora también se eliminaran las instancias relacionadas del modelo `Caracteristica`. Mira si obtienes el resultado deseado.

Comment: efectivamente borra todo el producto pero no es el objetivo, por que en si mi pregunta principal es descontar la cantidad del modelo con el aprobado de la order, aun asi muchas gracias hombre por colaborarme (y)

Comment: Entonces no quieres que elimine todas las instancias relacionadas del modelo `Caracteristica` verdad? debo restar el valor del campo `cantidad` verdad? si es así en base a que lo resto?

Comment: en si Caracteristica tiene un campo disponibles yo quiero que los productos agregados a mi orden que en si se encuentran en orderitem se asocia una cantidad que esta con default=1, quiero que cuando la order diga aprobado los productos de orderitem el campo cantidad se reste del campo disponibles de Caracteristica.

Comment: en definitva restar cantidad de orderitem a disponibles de Caracteristica cuando el campo estado=aprobado de order

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108473/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-ancizar-rubio).